# Getting data from firebase and putting it in recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

So, I am trying to get the data from firebase. To do that I am setting the addValueEventListener to the ref and overriding the onDataChange function. In the guidlines it is said that this is called the first time, but it is only being called when the data is being changed(like the name suggests) So because of this when I load my activity, I get nothing in the recyclerView.
In the listener I am adding all the objects to a List

```
This is the listener:
    protected void setListener() {
        originalValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                complaints.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Complaint post = postSnapshot.getValue(Complaint.class);
                    complaints.add(post);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
```

And from my activity I am retrieving this List with a function:

```
    public   List<Complaint> getComplaints() {
        return complaints;
    }
```

This is my activity:

ComplaintFeedAdapter adapter = new ComplaintFeedAdapter(getComplaints());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: My quick guess is that you're not calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` in `ComplaintFeedAdapter`. But without seeing the code for the adapter, it's impossible to be sure. Note that implementing an adapter is non-trivial. You might want to have a look at the ones in [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) for inspiration (or better yet, just use them).

Comment: Alright, creating a firebaseRecyclerAdapter worked. Thanks